# Trying to create custom log channel Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, monolog

Inside `config/logging.php`:

```
'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single', 'mongo'],
        ],

        'mongo' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => \Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler::class,
            'handler_with' => [
                'mongo' => new MongoDB\Client(),
                'database' => 'logs',
                'collection' => 'test'
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

`.env`: `LOG_CHANNEL=stack`

I'm sure that MongoDB database `logs` exists, `test` collection too.

I'm trying to log some data being inside `php artisan tinker`:

```
Log::info('test');
```

I got exception

> Expected [$document](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Client.php#L38) to have type "array or object" but found "string"

Even I try `php artisan config:cache` I got this exception.

What can be wrong?

---

Update:
`'mongo' => MongoDB\Client::class,` causes the same error. By the way, there is no word in documentation about passing class either class instance inside `handler_with` array.

This config

```
'mongo' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => \Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler::class,
        ]
```

also returns error, but I expected [InvalidArgumentException](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/MongoDBHandler.php#L52).

This one

```
'mongo' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'handler' => new \Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler(new MongoDB\Client(),'logs', 'prod'),
]
```

causes `LogicException  : Your configuration files are not serializable.`.

Comment: you can try Log::info(array('test'));

Comment: @MaheshHegde the problem is not there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sollution by [mfn](https://github.com/mfn):
add `formatter` to the channel array:

```
'formatter' => \Monolog\Formatter\MongoDBFormatter::class,
```

also create custom formatter class, because [mongo formatter](https://github.com/mfn) used in current Laravel version is out of date.

```
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of the Monolog package.
 *
 * (c) Jordi Boggiano <j.boggiano@seld.be>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace Monolog\Formatter;
/**
 * Formats a record for use with the MongoDBHandler.
 *
 * @author Florian Plattner <me@florianplattner.de>
 */
class MongoDBFormatter implements FormatterInterface
{
    private $exceptionTraceAsString;
    private $maxNestingLevel;
    /**
     * @param int  $maxNestingLevel        0 means infinite nesting, the $record itself is level 1, $record['context'] is 2
     * @param bool $exceptionTraceAsString set to false to log exception traces as a sub documents instead of strings
     */
    public function __construct($maxNestingLevel = 3, $exceptionTraceAsString = true)
    {
        $this->maxNestingLevel = max($maxNestingLevel, 0);
        $this->exceptionTraceAsString = (bool) $exceptionTraceAsString;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function format(array $record)
    {
        return $this->formatArray($record);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function formatBatch(array $records)
    {
        foreach ($records as $key => $record) {
            $records[$key] = $this->format($record);
        }
        return $records;
    }
    protected function formatArray(array $record, $nestingLevel = 0)
    {
        if ($this->maxNestingLevel == 0 || $nestingLevel <= $this->maxNestingLevel) {
            foreach ($record as $name => $value) {
                if ($value instanceof \DateTime) {
                    $record[$name] = $this->formatDate($value, $nestingLevel + 1);
                } elseif ($value instanceof \Exception) {
                    $record[$name] = $this->formatException($value, $nestingLevel + 1);
                } elseif (is_array($value)) {
                    $record[$name] = $this->formatArray($value, $nestingLevel + 1);
                } elseif (is_object($value)) {
                    $record[$name] = $this->formatObject($value, $nestingLevel + 1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $record = '[...]';
        }
        return $record;
    }
    protected function formatObject($value, $nestingLevel)
    {
        $objectVars = get_object_vars($value);
        $objectVars['class'] = get_class($value);
        return $this->formatArray($objectVars, $nestingLevel);
    }
    protected function formatException(\Exception $exception, $nestingLevel)
    {
        $formattedException = array(
            'class' => get_class($exception),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'code' => $exception->getCode(),
            'file' => $exception->getFile() . ':' . $exception->getLine(),
        );
        if ($this->exceptionTraceAsString === true) {
            $formattedException['trace'] = $exception->getTraceAsString();
        } else {
            $formattedException['trace'] = $exception->getTrace();
        }
        return $this->formatArray($formattedException, $nestingLevel);
    }
    protected function formatDate(\DateTime $value, $nestingLevel)
    {
        return new UTCDateTime($value->getTimestamp());
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

My own implementation so far:

`config/logging.php`:

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => [... , 'mongo'],
    ],

    ...

    'mongo' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'handler' => \Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler::class,
        'via' => \App\Logging\MongoLogger::class, //place MongoLogger where you want
        'name' => 'mongo',
        'host' => env('MONGODB_HOST'), //you can keep these right here in cofig, but I prefer .env because its scaleable
        'port' => env('MONGODB_PORT'),
        'database' => env('MONGODB_DATABASE'),
        'collection' => env('MONGODB_COLLECTION')
    ]
],
```

`MongoLogger` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging; //once again, palce this where you want

use App\MongoDBFormatter;
use MongoDB\Client;
use Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class MongoLogger
{
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
        $handler = new MongoDBHandler(
            new Client('mongodb://'.$config['host'].':'.$config['port']),
            $config['database'],
            $config['collection']
        );

        $handler->setFormatter(new MongoDBFormatter());

        return new Logger($config['name'], [$handler]);
    }
}
```

`MongoDBFormatter` class (modified a bit, [original one with some deprecated classes, by the way](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/1.x/src/Monolog/Formatter/MongoDBFormatter.php)):

```
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of the Monolog package.
 *
 * (c) Jordi Boggiano <j.boggiano@seld.be>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace App; //once again, palce this where you want

use Monolog\Formatter\FormatterInterface;

/**
 * Formats a record for use with the MongoDBHandler.
 *
 * @author Florian Plattner <me@florianplattner.de>
 */
class MongoDBFormatter implements FormatterInterface
{
    private $exceptionTraceAsString;
    private $maxNestingLevel;
    /**
     * @param int  $maxNestingLevel        0 means infinite nesting, the $record itself is level 1, $record['context'] is 2
     * @param bool $exceptionTraceAsString set to false to log exception traces as a sub documents instead of strings
     */
    public function __construct($maxNestingLevel = 3, $exceptionTraceAsString = true)
    {
        $this->maxNestingLevel = max($maxNestingLevel, 0);
        $this->exceptionTraceAsString = (bool) $exceptionTraceAsString;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function format(array $record)
    {
        return $this->formatArray($record);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function formatBatch(array $records)
    {
        foreach ($records as $key => $record) {
            $records[$key] = $this->format($record);
        }
        return $records;
    }
    protected function formatArray(array $record, $nestingLevel = 0)
    {
        if ($this->maxNestingLevel == 0 || $nestingLevel <= $this->maxNestingLevel) {
            foreach ($record as $name => $value) {
                if ($value instanceof \DateTime) {
                    $record[$name] = $this->formatDate($value, $nestingLevel + 1);
                } elseif ($value instanceof \Exception) {
                    $record[$name] = $this->formatException($value, $nestingLevel + 1);
                } elseif (is_array($value)) {
                    $record[$name] = $this->formatArray($value, $nestingLevel + 1);
                } elseif (is_object($value)) {
                    $record[$name] = $this->formatObject($value, $nestingLevel + 1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $record = '[...]';
        }
        return $record;
    }
    protected function formatObject($value, $nestingLevel)
    {
        $objectVars = get_object_vars($value);
        $objectVars['class'] = get_class($value);
        return $this->formatArray($objectVars, $nestingLevel);
    }
    protected function formatException(\Exception $exception, $nestingLevel)
    {
        $formattedException = array(
            'class' => get_class($exception),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'code' => $exception->getCode(),
            'file' => $exception->getFile() . ':' . $exception->getLine(),
        );
        if ($this->exceptionTraceAsString === true) {
            $formattedException['trace'] = $exception->getTraceAsString();
        } else {
            $formattedException['trace'] = $exception->getTrace();
        }
        return $this->formatArray($formattedException, $nestingLevel);
    }
    protected function formatDate(\DateTime $value, $nestingLevel)
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

[Answser source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25170).

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly your 'logger' wants to have an array of data. I guess it might be JSON format so you could try to json_decode it before entering it into your logger. It would be better to log to something else first to actually see the 'pushed' data first (a simple var dump will do).

Also, I do not have enough reputation yet to reply directly so please dont comment that this should have been a direct 'reply';

Comment: I think, the problem is with library or my config. But if I set up config correct, there might be no problems to log string.